# Bootstrap, datatable, result of filter method is ignored

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have the newest DataTable plugin. In document.ready:

```
$('#admin_users_table').DataTable().column(3).data().filter(function(v) {
  console.log(v+'         '+Math.random());
  return false;
});
```

it runs once when site loads, and logs the good values. Now, if I change a dropdown:

```
$('#admin_users_filter').change(function() {
  console.clear();
  $('#admin_users_table').DataTable().draw();
});
```

it wont work. Actually, the problem is no matter what the `return` is, it wont affect what rows gets draw and what are not.

Comment: Please show your markup / dataTables initialisation script if any, it is not totally clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: This problem description is horrible. Lots of mentions of `it` with no reference to what `it` is. Also no context shown for this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`filter()`**](https://datatables.net/reference/api/filter()) is not a search function that takes effect on the table. Its purpose is to let you extract content of the table as a new API instance, not to filter content.

Example, console out all rows where column #3 starts with a certain letter, chosen via a `<select>` box :

```js
$("#filter").change(function() {
    var that = this;
    var filteredValues = table.column(3).data().filter(function(value, index ) {
        return value.toLowerCase().substr(0,1) == that.value;
    })
    //console out all matches
    console.log(filteredValues);
})
```

If you want to filter the table programmatically, and not want to use the builtin `search()` function, you can implement a custom filter. The below does exactly the same as the above, but this time the action happens on the table itself :

```js
$("#search").change(function() {
  var that = this;  
  $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
     function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
        return data[3].toLowerCase().substr(0,1) == that.value;
     }
  )    
  table.draw();
  //reset the custom filter 
  $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop();  
});
```

both examples here -> **http://jsfiddle.net/khbt2hhm/**

Comment: yea, thats a nice solution but somehow it wont trigger: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33324589/fn-datatable-ext-search-wont-trigger

Comment: EDIT: if wont trigger if I set the "searching" to FALSE. If I let it, it do work then, but I dont want that search box......

Comment: @JohnSmith - `.dataTables_filter { display: none; }` to hide the search box permanently for users -> **http://jsfiddle.net/khbt2hhm/1/**